# How is the second shock in a lambda shock able to form?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, shock-waves

For an oblique shock to form, there has to be an angle in which the flow turns into itself. Usually, that angle is caused by flow separation, in which the separation is caused by a normal shock first, I think (this is what I've thought so far).

The first leg of a lambda shock is considered an oblique shock. For that to form there had to be a normal shock to cause the separation (or angle) needed. Since the flow behind a normal shock is always subsonic, how would the second leg of the lambda shock form?

There is a theory I have, not sure if it's correct : Supersonic enough flow causes separation on a wing. This would make it so there doesn’t have to be a normal shock to make separation, as it’s already there. So that makes just an oblique shock without the normal shock needing to be there.

And because flow can be supersonic after an oblique shock, that would answer my question. (Still not sure if I’m correct about any of the above).

Comment: Not sure I follow, how can flow still be supersonic downstream of a shock wave?  Doesn't that negate the entire premise of a shock wave?

Comment: @honeste_vivere You’re correct if it’s a normal shock. If it’s an oblique shock, flow can be supersonic after. Search “strong and weak shock solution”.

Comment: Something like this has always been my understanding. The second leg is another oblique shock formed by the same normal shock, but now normal to the surface perturbed by the separation and boudary layer https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/102904/

Comment: @whpowell96 But if the normal shock is first to create the separation, then how is the second leg able to form? Flow is always subsonic after a normal shock, and flow has to be supersonic for an oblique shock to form.

Comment: @Wyatt - I think you are misunderstanding something.  The total flow speed may be supersonic (I am still not sure about this) but the only speed that matters for a shock is the speed normal to the shock surface.  The transverse component can be transformed away since the only component that changes across a shock is the one normal to the shock surface.  So as I implied, the flow downstream is not really supersonic.  However, if the next piston/driver is a surface orthogonal to the transverse flow from 1st shock, then the transverse component matters and is still supersonic.  Does that help?

Comment: @honeste_vivere hmm okay, thanks. So if you look at [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102904/when-an-oblique-shock-forms-what-happens-to-the-normal-shock-that-helped-it-for) question, the answer has an image. I understand everything about it, but oblique shocks form because the flow turns into itself. The first leg of the shock is an oblique shock. So oblique shocks need a form of turning, and on a wing that is done by what? What causes the initial turning (separation) to allow the first shock to form? I think I kind of asked the wrong question to get my point across.

Comment: Ah okay, the separation occurs because the horizontal speed of the flow is higher than the speed of sound of the fluid.  That is, the fluid can't fully back-fill the area as fast as where the contact surface drops away.  The figure is a gross over exaggeration of what actually happens, as you can imagine.  The need for multiple shocks arises because of the changing cross-sectional area of the piston/driver and the shape not being one blunt transition/change.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Ahh, see that's the theory I was talking about in the original question. Thank you for confirming that!